# How to develop an application looks like VS.NET in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to develop Error List Control present in VS.NET into my application using WPF
Help me

Thank u!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [AvalonDocks](http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonDock)

Answer (score 0):

The error list in Visual Studio is essentially a DataGrid.  Check out the DataGrid control in the [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf).  If you are using 4.0, [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.100).aspx) is part of the framework.